# 2007 F250 Super duty Powerstroke 6.0 crank no start

Tags: ford, starting, troubleshooting, diesel, f-250

Ok I don't know Jack about diesel, but i am learning as I go! It has been running out of fuel when the DTE is at 65-58 miles and its keeps climbing. When i first got the truck a year ago it ran out at 38 miles.... Now with that being said that is NOT my issue or even my concern. But what is the other day i ran out of fuel, put $30 worth of fuel in it, turns over but won't start. Just in the past 7 month i have replaced: (routine maintenance: oil filter, glow plugs, fuel filters) (non routine:) starter, throttle pedal, IPR, MAP sensor, ICR sensor, and exhaust pressure sensor. Its acting like it's not getting fuel but it is getting fuel.  I'm lost as to where to go from here?? My only other thought is to really give it some fuel and some EXTRA heat to go with it!

Comment: Hi Amy. It's possible that this previous question has answers that apply to your specific situation: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/12052/57. Note @Paulster2's answer: it's possible that one or more components in the fuel supply chain have been damaged.

Comment: @Bob Cross- thank you! Its a start, I'm gonna go check a couple more things with the fuel system, let you know how it turns out!

Comment: good luck! If you figure it out, please come back and answer your question here. It will be a trail of breadcrumbs for the next person with a similar problem! (Plus I’ll vote up your answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have air in your injectors.
The first thing I would do is find the pump and purge any air from your fuel filter, (running out of fuel in a diesel is very hard on the injectors) once you get the air out then turn the key on and listen for the pump, when it stops turn the key off, then back on until it stops again do this 3-4 times this helps push air out of the lines and heats the glow plugs, then try and start it.
After having a diesel tractor that I had to crack the fuel lines at the injectors to bleed the air I never even get close to the bottom of the tank, use your odometer as a guide if your fuel gauge is not working, I get 250 miles pulling a 4 horse trailer or 310 no trailer as an example.
But with the newer motors usually cycling the key will clear any air bubbles in the injectors.